# Can you reuse the web design of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, legal

I have a question regarding more legal-oriented stuff. I am planning to create a support / developer page for my product, and I would like to have Stack Overflow look-a-like type of questions.

Is this under any license, or can I use the template and mix it a bit for my purposes?

Comment: FYI, At the bottom of this page: "site design / logo © 2015 stack exchange inc"

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett So this means that noone else can now use such system ?
To have questions on their page, which indicate whether they are answered or not ?

Comment: You could create/use such a system, but the UI design (images, CSS, etc) can't be taken from the StackExchange sites.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Ah! Of course not! That was not intention, probably I didn't ask good enough what I wanted. Basically, I want to have a system where users can see the questions of customers on homepage and see whether they are answered or not. That's all. Design: colours, images, text..will be done uniquely by me

Comment: Ahh ok, in that case I don't think StackExchange owns the rights to an online Q&A site. Someone more versed in things like this might give a better answer though.

Comment: [Stack Exchange clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/262755)

Answer (score 5):

Here is Stack's official [Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

---

I know you stated your question might not be clear, but I will answer your question *directly* for clarity.

> Can you re-use Web *design* of Stackoverflow?

Depends on what you mean by "design".

Individual colours and even basic layout/structures are not really owned by any website.

What is *potentially* copyrighted/trademarked is a "specific complete design" - specific colours in specific places *in conjunction* with other specific colours and layout etc - such as company branding which is trademarked/copyright throughout the company including away from the internet.

Of course, "content" and "specific design elements" can be (usually are) copyrighted/trademarked too - including logos, background images, and text.

And obviously things which are *officially* copyrighted/trademarked, such as in the case of Stack the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838).

---

> I am planning to create a support / developer page for my product, and
> I would like to have StackOverflow look-a-like type of questions

There are many Q&A style sites not part of Stack Exchange. And Stack do not own any copyrights to Q&A style websites, no-one can.
So you can make a site "similar" to Stack's Q&A just as Stack did when it started.

[Wikipedia - Q&A Website List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_question-and-answer_websites)

So creating a site where you have "questions and answers", even "comments and voting", would be fine. Just be careful not to copy (or re-produce) design or functionality which is unique to Stack.

e.g. It might be a "bit much" having a thin bar at the top with rep, user info, badges, notifications, then a taller coloured bar below it with links to questions, badges, etc.

Or your site has a "Hot Network Questions" list at the side...

---

> Design: colours, images, text..will be done uniquely by me

That is fine.

Stack is one (or 144) of over a billion websites, and with such large numbers layout "similarities" will always exist, by chance and accident.
You'd probs have somethings similar even if you'd never been to Stack and are making a Q&A site.

Just always consider the word "copy" - i.e. be careful coming to Stack and thinking "I'll also do that, and that, and put that on my site too" etc.

That's likely fine for *some* layout and most functionality, as there will be *many* other websites already similar, but when you start to copy *specific* layout, colours, styles, and functionality specific to Stack, you will be treading into "copy" territory rather than "inspirational" and "generic/similar to many".

### Unique is better

You don't want it to look *and* feel too much like Stack anyway, as your potential users might just think "This is a copy of Stack, how terrible is that" and you lose potential users because of it.
I wouldn't ever use any site which felt like it was a "copy" of another, just for the fact they copied someone else's work and are not original in some way (like Stack is original in their approach and ideas).

Besides, most people would use the "original" unless you had something better or unique to offer.
Like making a new "Twitter" or "Facebook" - why would anyone use yours over the main ones?